# Python, I'm using a generator but it doesn't work

Tags: python, generator

I made this generator and it works perfectly.

```
# - Function generator
def polyF(matrix, i=1):
    if i == 1: yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]; i+=1
    while i > 1: 
      matrix = np.hstack((matrix, matrix[:, 0:1]**i))
      i+=1
      yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]
```

But it doesn't look aesthetically beautiful. So I tried something like this but it doens't work at all and I was wondering why this is not working.

```
# - Function generator
def polyF(matrix, i=1):
    while i > 1: 
      matrix = np.hstack((matrix, matrix[:, 0:1]**i))
      i+=1
      yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]
    yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]; i+=1
getP = polyF(X)
```

when I'm using next(getP) this is the error message I got.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-91b0148b3536> in <module>()
     25 
     26     # - Predicting yP
---> 27     X_ = next(getP)
     28     W = np.linalg.inv( X_.T @ X_ ) @ X_.T @ Y
     29     yP = W @ X_.T
StopIteration:
```

What's happening?

Comment: Sorrry, updated, even though it only shows "StopIteration"

Comment: The generator which is throwing the error is `GetP`, not `PolyF`, no ?

Comment: @SimonR Yeah, but it's a variable where I saved the generator in order to use next(getP)

Comment: Oh my bad- sorry, I completely misread your code!

Comment: Your first and second iterator are very obviously not equivalent - the initial one adds a leading element, the latter one adds a trailing element. Why do you assume them to be interchangeable? Why do you manually iterate over the generator (using ``next``) instead of iterating over all elements (using ``for`` or ``map``)? What is your logic to see if the generator is empty?

Comment: Calling `next` on a generator will inevitably raise a `StopIteration` exception once the generator is exhausted.

Comment: `StopIteration` means the generator exhausted all of its values, and you're trying to get more.  There aren't any more.

Comment: So why the first code isn't throwing up "Stop Iteration"? I used to think that when I call "next" it would be like say "ok now do this for n+1 element", and so on, in order not to saturate the memory (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: In the first version, what is the purpose of the `; i += 1`? Will the `while` loop be entered when the initial value of `i` is `1`? Now, what happens in the second version?

Comment: In the second function, the `while i > 1` loop never runs, because `i` starts at 1.  Only the final `yield` executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I want to help you actually make the code "aesthetically beautiful" as you put it, and because I've learned that I can't actually rely on codereview.stackexchange.com being helpful with this sort of thing, here's my attempt.

First, we notice that inside the loop, the `i += 1` can be moved after the `yield`, because it doesn't affect the expression in the `yield`. Then, those two lines (I separate the `; i+= 1` as a separate line) are repeated:

```
def polyF(matrix, i=1):
    if i == 1: 
        yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]  # A
        i+=1                                           # B
    while i > 1: 
        matrix = np.hstack((matrix, matrix[:, 0:1]**i))
        yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]  # A
        i+=1                                           # B
```

Therefore, we can let the loop handle this, by first setting the loop bounds to include `1`, and *excluding* the `hstack` step when `i == 1`:

```
def polyF(matrix, i=1):
    while i > 0:
        if i != 1:
            matrix = np.hstack((matrix, matrix[:, 0:1]**i))
        yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]
        i+=1
```

Next, I notice that the `while` condition is intended to loop infinitely for strictly positive `i`, and do nothing for zero or negative `i`. The latter seems enough like a special case that I want to handle it explicitly. That also allows me to use the standard library to handle the "counting" logic for `i`:

```
import itertools

def polyF(matrix, i=1):
    if i < 1:
        return # but maybe we should raise an exception instead?
    for degree in itertools.count(i):
        if degree != 1:
            matrix = np.hstack((matrix, matrix[:, 0:1]**degree))
        yield np.c_[np.ones(matrix.shape[0]), matrix]
```

(I didn't test this, and I'm not sure I understand what is going on mathematically either. So please test it carefully, but hopefully it is at least close enough to help you.)

Comment: It works perfectly, I still have some problems in order to understand how a generator works, but I got the point, thanks a lot!